# How does JSX render the {foo => [ <bar />, <baz /> ]} syntax?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I've just seen the above syntax on a CodeSandbox, and as far as I'd always learned you cannot render arrays in JSX - you must always `map` them if you want to render something for each of the array items.

Here's the code I saw:

```
render(
<React.StrictMode>
    <HigherOrderComponent>
        {permissions => [
            <Resource name="posts" {...posts} />,
            <Resource name="comments" {...comments} />,
            permissions ? <Resource name="users" {...users} /> : null,
            <Resource name="tags" {...tags} />,
        ]}
    </HigherOrderComponent>
</React.StrictMode>,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

[And here's the CSB](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/examples/simple?from-embed=&file=/src/index.tsx:645-1664)

How does that `permissions` inline JavaScript work? I think it's also very curious that `permissions` is not defined anywhere in the file.

Answer (score 1):

It will just render all of them as sibling nodes

```
[<Foo/>, <Bar/>]
```

is equivalent to

```
<>
  <Foo/>
  <Bar/>
</>
```

For example, this will render as `<p>hello</p><p>world</p>`

```js
const App = () => [
  <p>hello</p>,
  <p>world</p>,
];
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends entirely on what `HigherOrderComponent` does. Since React doesn't limit `children` of an element to actually be JSX elements, you can do just that (or any other function-shape render prop).

I would assume HigherOrderComponent is something like (**EDIT:** [I was more or less correct](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/5ae855aa958ba54438b144bf0907b1437c5a5d77/packages/ra-core/src/core/CoreAdminRouter.tsx#L114-L146))

```
function HigherOrderComponent({children}) {
  const permissions = usePermissions();  // fictional hook to return permissions
  const childFunc = React.Children.only(children);
  const realChildren = childFunc(permissions);
  return <>{realChildren}</>;
}
```

(see [React.Children.only()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrenonly)).